# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Role.CreatedBy' of type 'User'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-model-builder

I am using .NET 6 to develop EF Core MVC program, The concept is single User can have multiple roles, and the role data is create by a User from another system.

I have a base class **EntityBase.cs** :

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And a base class **CreatableEntity.cs** inherited **EntityBase.cs** again

```
public abstract class CreatableEntity : EntityBase
{
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Then have a **User.cs** class inherited **CreatableEntity** class

```
public class User : CreatableEntity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

And have a **Role.cs** class inherited **CreatableEntity** class also

```
public class Role : CreatableEntity
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

And **UserRole.cs** class is the table to store "UserId" and "RoleId"

```
public class UserRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Users { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Roles { get; set; }
}
```

The OnModelCreating in my context class

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{     
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasBaseType((Type)null)
            .HasKey(rb => rb.CreatedById);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
           .HasMany(u => u.Roles)
           .WithMany(u => u.Users)
           .UsingEntity<UserRole>(
               j => j
                   .HasOne(ua => ua.Roles)
                   .WithMany(a => a.UserRoles)
                   .HasForeignKey(ua => ua.UserId),
               j => j
                   .HasOne(ua => ua.Users)
                   .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
                   .HasForeignKey(ua => ua.RoleId)
               j =>
               {
                   j.HasKey(ua => new { ua.RoleId, ua.UserId });
               });
    }
}
```

When I run the program, hit the following error:

**Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Role.CreatedBy' of type 'User'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.**

I researching some time and found a article from Microsoft : [mapping using base and derived types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance)

I am tried to implement it but still get error, how should I solve it?

Comment: `public virtual User Users { get; set; }` <-- This is a _singular_ property, yet you gave it a plural name...

Comment: What is the purpose of `CreatableEntity`? _Every_ EF entity type is "creatable"... (also using inheritance in EF entity classes causes no-end of problems, just warning you)

Comment: Hi Dai, most of my DB table have column `CreatedById` to record the data is created by which `User`. So I designed a `CreatableEntity` as base for it, so that I can just inherit it instead of add `CreatedById` to all my classes. And the `CreatedById` is foreign key, to link the `User` data during get the record.

Comment: Don't abuse inheritance as a substitute for mixins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with following changes:

**User.cs**

```
public class User : CreatableEntity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }  <-- get the Role data from UserRole instead of here

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**Role.cs**

```
public class Role : CreatableEntity
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    //public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }  <-- get the User data from UserRole instead of here

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**UserRole.cs**

```
[Table("UserRoles")]   <-- This changes to match with DB table name, else will hit invalid object name 'UserRole'
public class UserRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Users { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Roles { get; set; }
}
```

**OnModelCreating**

```
public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
//public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }  <-- no need declare also doesn't matter

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
        .HasOne(r => r.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(r => r.CreatedById);

     modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
        .HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
        .HasOne(ur => ur.Users)
        .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
        .HasOne(ur => ur.Roles)
        .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
        .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId);
}
```

[image]